# How to preserve quotes in a Rails form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webforms

How does one preserve the original quotes?  The quotes are required when submitting a quoted search string, for example.

- Search form example1: ruby "new york"
- Search from example2: "new york"

Resulting params[:q]:

- for example1: "ruby \"new york\""
- for example2: "new york"

Note that Rails throws away quotes if the entire string is quoted, as in example2. But in example1, the quotes are preserved since they are interspersed within the string. I need example2 to preserve the quotes so I see params[:q] as "\"new york\"".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Rails bug that has long since been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about sql injectioning you want to search using `"test me"` and not `"\"test me"\"`.

Use following to search

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions=>["(username like :text)",{:text=>"%#{params[:search_text]}%"}])
```

Comment: Search form example1: ruby "new york" ---
Search from example2: "new york" ---
Resulting params[:q]: 
for example1: "ruby \"new york\"" ---
for example2: "new york" ---

Note that Rails throws away quotes if the entire string is quoted, as in example2.  But in example1, the quotes are preserved since they are interspersed within the string.  I need example2 to preserve the quotes so I see params[:q] as "\"new york\"".